# Custom button shape

Tags: c++, windows, button, bitmap

I want to implement a simple volume up/down button using a custom bitmap, and all it's going to have is a simple hover effect, and mouse down effect.
My first idea was to process `WM_MOUSEMOVE` for the hover, and process `WM_LBUTTONUP` and `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` for the mouse down effect.

First, is this the easiest way to do this? I could superclass a button and just paint the bitmap and forget about the text...

Then I have the problem with the background, which should be transparent, I know I can use a mask by passing `SRCAND` to `BitBlt`, but this requires me to have 2 images for each button. Is there any way to do this with just one image? Like if I put a green background on it in my image editor, could I mask that out with a green screen like effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a regular button, and subclass it with [SetWindowSubclass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The button must have the owner-draw style on it, which means in the parent WndProc, you are handling [WM_DRAWITEM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775923%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). As you correctly say, you will be [BitBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)'ing or [StretchBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)'ing the background of the image on.

For hover events you must do the following:

- Have some sort of shared boolean between the parent and subclassed WndProc, eg. `IsMousedOver`
- In the subclassed WndProc, process [WM_MOUSEMOVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645616.aspx). When this message is hit, you should set `IsMousedOver`, then invalidate the control with [InvalidateRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145002%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (this will trigger `WM_DRAWITEM` in the parent)
- In the parent WndProc, if you receive `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, you should clear `IsMousedOver`
- In `WM_DRAWITEM` in the parent WndProc, you should check IsMousedOver and BitBlt based on that state

If you want to process MouseUp/MouseDown, you can change the boolean to an int instead and have a tri-state. However, most implementations have MouseDown being the same as the regular button, and MouseUp is then simply the regular moused over background.

As for your query about 2 images, it may well be possible to do it with one but I haven't tried that before.

Comment: How should I create the shared boolean? I've heard so many times that global variables are pure evil. So, is there any other way to create a shared variable(s)?

Comment: One idea I had was to take a object oriented approach and create a button class, where the initializer calls `CreateWindow`, and it saves the state and other information as private members. But then I still need to have a class for each button, and they would most likely have to be global.

Comment: Unfortunately I program C, not C++ so there's not really any other option. I am sure you can think of some object oriented way to encapsulate the boolean properly though :)